# Bookmark required for non-empty scalars

Tags: fixtures, isis

I’m working with a project that’s built on Apache Causeway.  So far we’ve been using version 2.0.0-RC2, but we need to get it updated to 2.0.0-RC4.  I found that one of our unit tests fails under the new version, but I can’t quite figure out why.  The root cause of the failure happens in this line of the test code:

```
        fixtureScripts.run(new RuleDefinition_persona.PersistAll());
```

where `RuleDefinition_persona` is an enum implementing `Persona<RuleDefinition, RuleDefinition_persona.Builder>` containing three example RuleDefinition persistence entities.  In Causeway -RC2 this call runs normally, but in -RC4 we get an error:

> java.lang.AssertionError: bookmark required for non-empty scalars ObjectSpecificationDefault@2f2e4c19[class=rpe.modules.rules.dom.rule.RuleDefinition,type=ENTITY,superclass=rpe.modules.rules.dom.audited.AuditedEntity] ==> expected:  but was:

I’ve looked through the documentation, release notes, and migration notes for -RC3 and -RC4 but can’t find anything regarding bookmarks or “non-empty scalars”.  Furthermore I’ve looked at the Causeway source code where this assertion is tested — org.apache.causeway.core.runtimeservices.executor.MemberExecutorServiceDefault:188 — and it looks like this code hasn’t changed between RC2 and RC4.  Does anyone have an idea what change would cause this assertion to fail?  And does this require a change to our test code, or could it be the result of a bug in Causeway?

(The test class extends `CausewayIntegrationTestAbstractWithFixtures`.)

Test method:

```
    @Test
    public void happyCase() {

        // given
        fixtureScripts.run(new RuleDefinition_persona.PersistAll());
        interactionService.nextInteraction();

        // when
        final List<RuleDefinition> all = wrap(menu).listAll();

        // then
        assertThat(all).hasSize(RuleDefinition_persona.values().length);
    }
```

Expected that the test passes; in other words, `all` (the menu list) has 3 items.  The actual result is a failure:

```
Expected size: 3 but was: 0 in:
[]
```

If the first line of the test method is changed to:

```
        fixtureScripts.runPersonas(RuleDefinition_persona.values());
```

then the root cause of the failure is revealed:

```
java.lang.AssertionError: bookmark required for non-empty scalars ObjectSpecificationDefault@2f2e4c19[class=rpe.modules.rules.dom.rule.RuleDefinition,type=ENTITY,superclass=rpe.modules.rules.dom.audited.AuditedEntity] ==> expected: <true> but was: <false>
```

Comment: You might want to take this question onto the causeway slack group ... https://causeway.apache.org/docs/latest/support/slack-channel.html ; we can try to help you there.

Comment: @DanHaywood I wasn’t able to subscribe to the mailing list; the mail server rejected my confirmation reply with:
> 550 5.7.23 : Recipient address rejected: ASF gnomes rejected your message: SPF fail - not authorized. See https://infra.apache.org/mail-rejection.html
I can’t request access to the Slack group without access to the mailing list.

Comment: I can set you up on the slack group though I need your email.  I don't imagine you want to post your email here, but if you google "dan haywood causeway email" you'll find mine easily enough.